# Pushing result to an object

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is running some calculations. I want to push the results into an object so I can return and insert HTML with the result dynamically displayed in the correct place.

So for example, how can I push the result stored in the variable totalSaving to the object surveyResults? I want savings: inside the object to be totalSaving from the calculation inside the function calc. So essentially I want the object to be updated with the calculations so I can display them on my site.

Thanks

```js
const calculate = document.getElementById('one');

const resultsContainer = document.querySelector('.card-wrapper-results');

calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);

let surveyResults = [
    {
        savings: 10.23,
        price: 35.84
    }
];

let chartResults = [
    {
        year1: 200,
        year2: 300,
        year3: 400,
        year4: 500,
        year6: 600,
        year7: 700,
        year8: 800,
        year9: 900,
        year10: 100
    }
];

let yearlySavings;
let scrappagePayment;
let smartPayment;

function calc() {
    event.preventDefault();
    let gas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let smartSaving;
    let result;
    let totalSaving;
    smartSaving = gas * 0.2;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    totalSaving = smartSaving + gasSaving;
    result = price - totalSaving;

    let displayResults = surveyResults.map(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        return `<div class="card2-results">
            
            
                <h1>Monthly Gas Savings</h1>
                <p class="job-title">Instant Savings</p>
                <h2 class="about-h2">
                    ${item.savings}
                </h2>
                <ul class="about-payment">
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Start Saving Straightaway</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 30% Saving From EcoTech Plus </li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 18% Saving From Hive Smart Heating</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Hive Smart Heating System Included</li>
                
                
                </ul>
            
                <a href="" class="btn-results">1st Year £336</a>
            
            </div>`;
    });
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = displayResults;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*to push the results into an object*"?

Comment: well for example, if after the calculations, the variable totalSavings = 50. I want to update savings: 10.23 in the object surveyResults to savings: 50. So when I dynamically add ${item.savings} into my html the number is correct.

Comment: Are you aware that your `surveyResults` is an **array** of objects?

Comment: I am now. I'm new to this. Sorry...

Comment: So? Do you still have questions?

Comment: Yes, the question still stands. How can I update the object savings within the array surveryResults with the value of totalSavings

Answer (score 0):

If the below does not answer your question, then provide clarifications.

```js
let surveyResults = [
    {
        savings: 10.23,
        price: 35.84
    }
];

let totalSaving=50;

surveyResults[0].savings=totalSaving;
console.log(surveyResults);
```